# Running commands from PHP exec shows different result than from shell

Tags: php, exec

The PHP `exec` command is not executing the same as the shell's interaction.

```
cd /var/www/myfolder
zip -r /var/www/myfolder/temp/newfile.zip  ./*
```

generates just a zip of files in the `temp` directory. However (simplified version):

```
$zip_dir = '/var/www/myfolder';
$temp_dir = $zip_dir . '/temp/';
chdir($zip_dir);
exec('zip -r ' . $temp_dir . 'newfile.zip ./*', $return);
```

generates the same zip but with the full path's of `var` and  `www` (which results in two copies of `myfolder` so my file is twice as large as needed).  The `$return` however has the same output as the command line execution. Both state only 15 files directories/folders were zipped. There is no mention of `var` or `www` in the PHP output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `chdir()` command will not have any bearing on how the commands in `exec()` are run. So this might fix it:

```
$zip_dir = '/var/www/myfolder';
$temp_dir = $zip_dir . '/temp/';
$cmd = 'cd ' . escapeshellarg($zip_dir) . ' && zip -r ' . escapeshellarg($temp_dir . 'newfile.zip') . ' ./*';
exec($cmd, $return);
```

Note we **always** escape variables being passed to the command line.

But why not just zip within PHP?

```
<?php
$zip_target = "/var/www/myfolder";
$zip_file = "/var/www/myfolder/temp/newfile.zip";


$zip_temp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'a458');
$zip_obj = new \ZipArchive();

if ($zip_obj->open($zip_temp, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE)) {
    $zip_obj->addGlob("$zip_target/**/*.*");
}
$zip_obj->close();
rename($zip_temp, $zip_file);
```

Comment: That behaves the same, I also tried `exec('pwd', $result);` which showed the `dir` was changed. The `ZipArchive` is a better approach, still interested in why the `exec` behavior varies. This resolves my issue though. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting, if you wanted to troubleshoot further the output might be more helpful with `-v` on the command line. But falling back to external programs should be a last resort sort of thing anyway.